# Crash on AutoLayout: Location anchors require being paired

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, autolayout

The app is crashing on `Location anchors require being paired.`. I would like to fix it, however no matter how many times did I manually tested the app with this view, I've never run into the crash (got only logs on Crashlytics). Anyone knows what may be wrong here, under what circumstances the crash may happen?

The property `centerYConstraint` is required because later it allows the user to move the view up/down.

Part of `MyView.m` file. The crash happens on setting `self.centerYConstraint`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.centerYConstraint = [self.view.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.parentViewController.view.centerYAnchor 
                                                      constant:self.view.center.y - self.parentViewController.view.center.y];
    self.centerYConstraint.active = YES;
}
```

Crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
NSLayoutConstraint for <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x16764ae0 "MyView:0x18e6b900.centerY">: 
A constraint cannot be made from <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x16764ae0 "MyView:0x18e6b900.centerY"> to a constant. 
Location anchors require being paired.
```

Comment: This error is a little bit misleading but I got it when view which anchor I was constraint it to was nil. In your case that would be self.parentViewController.view. But from code you provided I don't know  how that view can be nil in your case.

Comment: @Borbea Thanks, I was thinking about the same case. At the moment I've added logs to this point with printing the value and releasing it to the public. In a month I should have enough data to find out if that's the issue.

Comment: The question as posed lacks sufficient information and adding a bounty won’t change that.

Answer (score 2):

This exception happens when `constraintEqualToAnchor:self.parentViewController.view.centerYAnchor` gives `nil`, which might be when `self.parentViewController.view` is `nil`, or `self.parentViewController` is `nil`.

All hierarchy logic is not clear from description, but the following does solve the issue (assuming that superview is a view of parent controller, otherwise just some more conditions should be added).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.centerYConstraint = [self.view.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.superview.centerYAnchor 
                                                      constant:self.view.center.y - self.superview.center.y];
    self.centerYConstraint.active = YES;
}
```

Comment: I understand the bounty is tempting, but this is basically just a shot in the dark that might not even reach the original OP (note the bounty comes from somebody else). Whether `superview` is indeed the correct one to center for is not clear from the question. You're basically just saying "if you do something different, the crash won't happen"... :D